Join two table and get the sum and average rate with where condition laravel
I have 2 tables:
Transaction tables - where the order was been processed, amount, product id, productname
Reviews- Reviews for every product.
What I want is to join the transaction table and reviews and then, on the transaction, display the product name, and total amount of that product in the table transaction with the condition of status = completed and then join the reviews table to calculate the rate of the specific product.
transaction table
reviews table
RAting table and Product
$join = DB::table('transactions')->select('transactions.productid')->selectRaw('SUM(transactions.amount) as totalamount')->join('reviews','transactions.productid', '=', 'reviews.productid')->where('transactions.busid', '=', $user)->where('transactions.status', '=', 'Completed')->groupBy('transactions.productid')->get();

i tried that but it doesnt display the right total amount for the PR0001 - 1255
this code is working, but it doesnt have a join:
        $topProduct = Transaction::where('busid', $user)->select([DB::raw('SUM(amount) as amount'), DB::raw('productname as productname'), (DB::raw('count(productid) as prodcount'))])
            ->where('status', 'completed')->groupBy('productname')->orderBy('amount', 'desc')->get();

what i want is a join table with the rate: to display the rate of the products, anyone here can help me what is the right code for this?

Do you want the rating only for the completed transactions or do you want them for all transactions?

i want the completed transactions only, do you have any idea? please help me

Do you have an Eloquent relationship between a transaction and the reviews that belong to it? $transaction->reviews?

no, i want to use the db query.

Your solution could be something like this.
$results = Transaction::query()
        ->select('productId, productname')
        ->selectRaw('SUM(amount) as amount')
        ->selectRaw('COUNT(productid) as prodcount')
        ->selectRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT orderid) as amount_of_orders')
        ->selectSub(
            Review::query()
                ->selectRaw('AVG(rate)')
                ->whereColumn('reviews.productid', 'transactions.productid'),
            'avg_rating'
        )
        ->where('busid', $user)
        ->where('status', 'completed')
        ->groupBy('productId')
        ->orderBy('amount', 'desc')
        ->get();

I've splitted the selects for readability.

We use a count distinct to count the unique orders of the grouped by products. So if an order has the same product twice, then only one will be counted.
We use a sub query to get the average rate of the product. The second parameter of this function will be the name for this column.

